# How to Convert a Nested List to a DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested, nested-lists

I have a json of Air Quality data from an API. The output looks as follow:

```
data[0]

{'94103': [{'AQI': 34,
   'Category': {'Name': 'Good', 'Number': 1},
   'DateObserved': '2017-10-09 ',
   'HourObserved': 0,
   'Latitude': 37.75,
   'LocalTimeZone': 'PST',
   'Longitude': -122.43,
   'ParameterName': 'OZONE',
   'ReportingArea': 'San Francisco',
   'StateCode': 'CA'},
  {'AQI': 100,
   'Category': {'Name': 'Moderate', 'Number': 2},
   'DateObserved': '2017-10-09 ',
   'HourObserved': 0,
   'Latitude': 37.75,
   'LocalTimeZone': 'PST',
   'Longitude': -122.43,
   'ParameterName': 'PM2.5',
   'ReportingArea': 'San Francisco',
   'StateCode': 'CA'}]}
```

The list is nested by zipcodes, and I requested over 400 records. I want to be able to generate a dataframe indexed by zipcodes with my attributes ('AQI','Category' etc.) as columns.

Do I need to create a dictionary before converting to a dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in x.items()}) for x in data])
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! And if I wanted my Zipcode just as another variable (i.e. not indexed), what would you change to the code you shared?

Comment: Then add `.reset_index()`

Comment: All together `df = pd.concat([pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in x.items()}) for x in data]).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'zip'})`